# android camera preview occur fail to camera service error

Tags: android

I want when I click start button, showing camera preview.

but not work.

I use `setPreviewDisplay` `startPreview`

it is occur `RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service`

```
public class AndroidCamera extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    private static Camera camera = null;
    private Camera camera;
    private static Camera camera2 = null;

    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceView surfaceView2;

    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder2;

    Button buttonStartCameraPreview, buttonStopCameraPreview;
    boolean previewing = false;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        buttonStartCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startcamerapreview);
        buttonStopCameraPreview = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopcamerapreview);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceview);

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        buttonStartCameraPreview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (!previewing) {
                    camera = Camera.open(0);

                    if (camera != null) {
                        try {
                            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);

                            camera.startPreview();   //occur exception 

                            previewing = true;
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {


    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {

    }
}
```

I use manifest Permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera2" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"/>
```

thanks 
please advice for me

Comment: Have you checked that the camera is working outside of the app? Sometimes the camera will stop working until the device is rebooted.

Comment: @DogLover    another app work camera, and I try reboot my device, but same error

Comment: Are you targeting API Level 23 (Android M)? If so, are you handling runtime permissions correctly? You need to request the camera permission from the user: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html .


Also, include the full logcat including not just your app, for more debugging help. The camera service will likely log why it won't let you connect.